# What will be the code for Include Category

Tags: php, joomla

The following joomla plugin code is to select for Exclude Category from Joomla Category and I would like to know how to make it Include Category.

```
class plgContentExtcustomhtml extends JPlugin {
public function onContentAfterDisplay($context, &$row, &$params, $page=0)   {
if($context == 'com_content.article') {

//exclude
$ext_exclude_categories     = $this->params->get('ext_exclude_categories', 0);
$ext_exclude_articles       = $this->params->get('ext_exclude_articles', '');

//exclude category
if(!empty($ext_exclude_categories) AND strlen(array_search($row->catid, $ext_exclude_categories))){
return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you asking how to construct a MySQL query, add new parameters, etc...  Not really clear what you end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

the code above is from a plugin.
It works only if the current page is to show an article and the category isnot in the excluded categories.

If you want to change the logic and force it to work only for the excluded categories, then I think that you neeed to change:

```
//exclude category
if(!empty($ext_exclude_categories) AND strlen(array_search($row->catid, $ext_exclude_categories))){
return false;
}
```

to this:

```
//exclude category
if(empty($ext_exclude_categories) OR !strlen(array_search($row->catid, $ext_exclude_categories))){
return false;
}
```

Backup your code first. :-)

Comment: all i need is work the opposite...its excludes categories and article here...and i want INCLUDE categories or articles...not exclude anything..is it possible with the given code?